# A lock that refuses same-thread reentrant but allows different thread reentrant

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Is there a lock or other synchronization primitive that satisfies the following rules:

- The lock has infinite permits,
- Any single thread can only get up to one permit,
- A thread that doesn't hold a permit can always get a permit, immediately,
- When a thread is refused a permit (*i.e.* it already holds one), it should return a `boolean` rather than block (duh).

I know I can probably construct this myself using an `AbstractQueuedSynchronizer` but I've never played with this and currently I just need an out-of-the-box working bugless solution. (and I'm curious if it exists)

One more thing:

- No libraries allowed beyond adding one or two extra classes

Comment: I think using "ThreadLocal" object as a flag variable can solve your problem.

Comment: How does this constitute a lock? It never seems to block.

Comment: @Porcelain is right, this is like a per-thread caching, maybe a `ThreadLocal<OnceCalculatedResult>` would fit. Porcelan means set a boolean in your guarded work and check it the next time.

Comment: As others have noted, no knowledge of other threads is required to do this.  But you shouldn't need a ThreaLocal either.  If you can't do it with a simple boolean field, then your program is probably badly designed.

Answer (score 8):

What you describe is not a synchronization tool of any kind, it just about the opposite: preventing any interference between threads. Your tool has single-threaded semantics which must be invariant to the number of threads using it.

Therefore, as suggested in the comments, a `ThreadLocal<Boolean>` seems like a perfect match for it.